# Python doesn't run in CPanel / throws error

Tags: python, cpanel

I am a PHP developer and was tasked with writing a Python script. I am lost.

Short summary:
My client wants to log which directory and file, on which URL was visited by which IP

My code:

```
import sys
import os 
import io
import os.path
import socket
import requests
directory = os.getcwd()
ip =  os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
hostname = socket.gethostname()
i = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

If I may ask two questions:

1. How do I run Python on Cpanel? I have uploaded the file `example.py` and navigated to the file, but the page only displays the code.
2. On the above code (in online code testers), I get an error: `KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'`. What am I doing wrong

Comment: [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) is a dictionary containing your environment variables. It throws a KeyError when the environment variable can't be found. The "REMOTE_ADDR" environment variable doesn't appear to be defined on your system (or whichever system this is running on)

Comment: @byxor. Thanks. With my limited knowledge of Python, I thought I fixed that by including the `import os`. How can I fix that?

Comment: No worries. That's good, you want to import `os` so you have access to `os.environ` with your environment variables, but you still have an undefined environment variable (`REMOTE_ADDR`). You would need to set this environment variable on the machine that's running your code before running your python script. It appears that it isn't set. Perhaps you expect that it will already be set, but it isn't. Perhaps you mistyped it, or misconfigured your environment. It's hard to say without more details, and honestly I don't have any experience with cpanel